# Compromised machine. Should I create a partition or volume to install a clean OS?

Tags: macos, system-compromise

My goal is to create a 100% clean environment where I can interact with cryptocurrencies. For that, I can partition my disk or I can create a volume. Which one should I prefer?

Some context about the options:

https://old.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/90mr0u/partition_for_beta_testing/

> I decided to try the APFS volume (not partition). I made one and installed Mojave on it, and as far as I can tell it works as effectively as partitioning, in that macOS did not complain that I had two boot systems on one Mac. The APFS volume seemed to be just as good a wall between the systems.

> What I do not know yet is, if I no longer need the Mojave volume, will it be any easier to delete the APFS volume than it was to delete a partition. That message above said it would be...but we'll find out later.

Comment: Neither.  Simply boot the computer from a live-boot USB containing an ISO of your favorite Linux distro.

Comment: My favorite Linux distro is macOS

Comment: How do I do what you suggested for macOS? I don't want to lose files on this OS when I replug it. Also ideally I don't want to rely on an external device but first I guess I should try it with an external device

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mac, but you can do this using Ubuntu. See ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview. According to these instructions, this even works on Apple hardware, i.e. you can follow this procedure to live-boot your Mac into Ubuntu.